# Wordpress Child Theme Css not Working

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, parent-child

I am using the theme "inkness"
I have created a new folder named "inkness-child" and created there a css file named main.css

But nothing happens when I modify the main.css in the "inkness-child" theme, but it always works on the parent theme. I also used "!important", but still nothing.

And I also activated the child theme, but the modifications does not work.

Here is the code to main.css in the child theme:

```
/*
    Theme Name:   Inkness Child
    Theme URI:    http://click-victor.cu.cc/inkness-child/
    Description:  Inkness Child Theme
    Author:       Me
    Author URI:   http://click-victor.cu.cc
    Template:     inkness
    Version:      1.0.0

    @import url("../inkness/css/skins/main.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
   ------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Can you please show me what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name of child theme's css file to style.css

Note that the style.css file is enqueued automatically when you create the child theme.